# RichFaces calendar i18n - plug other than English locale

Tags: jsf, internationalization, calendar, richfaces

We use `rich:calendar` component.

It's default locale is English - names of months and other labels.

How to plug other than `En` locale?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the locale by the `locale` attribute which points to [`java.util.Locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```xml
<rich:calendar locale="#{bean.locale}" />
```

Or when you already have a `<f:view locale="#{bean.locale}">` for i18n:

```xml
<rich:calendar locale="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}" />
```

#### See also:

- [RichFaces 3.3.x Developer Guide - `<rich:calendar>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html)